# Windows Network Share Issues

Tags: windows, network-shares, shared-folders

I'm having trouble setting up windows homegroup and network shares on two windows 8 computers, a desktop and a Laptop.

I want to be able to have full access from my PC to my Laptops Shares and at the same time allow everybody to read files in those shares. So I set up the network share, giving everybody read permission and "MyComputer\Administrators" full access privileges.

However how can I log on to the network share from my Desktop using the credentials of my Laptop (the user credentials on both systems are identical by the way).

Using net use I get an "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed" error...

On another attempt using Homegroup shares, it seems like windows is having issues setting the homegroup up properly on the desktop. I selected to share all my users folders (pictures etc.) but they won't show up in the homegroup, on the laptop they do. Only after sharing a random folder with the homegroup, my desktop became visible to the laptop at all.

A question aside: under "Advanced sharing settings" there is a point "homegroup connections" what does it exactly do?

Regards,
Xaser

Comment: Hi, how did you connect them together using a local router?

Comment: Yes I did. However something seems to be messed up with windows network sharing or my setup anyway, I now tried to set everything up using homegroup and now the weirdest things happen.. Laptop can't see desktop, desktop can't see itself (homegroup that is) and I have no idea whats going on

Comment: I assume you're using DHCP configured. Right?

Comment: yes, thats correct.. I have also updated the question with further information